# Cross platform socket library - Android and IOS

Tags: android, ios, sockets

I need to develop a few cross platform application(s). These applications require networking and simple UI but very complex math behind them. I have the math part as ANSI-C optimized fashion, the UI, I like to use Gideros or MOAI but for networking I am not so sure.

The LUA sockets is a good option but doesn't really exactly give me what I want so I am looking for a simple cross platform socket library where I can use and port both platforms without a lot of hassle. Are there any such library?

Comment: do you actually NEED sockets? can you just use the built in Android networking classes?

Comment: @toadzky the other side (i.e. not phone) is a peripheral with Wifi. That wifi can send data via sockets so I assumed I need sockets

Comment: i would check if it accepts any kind of http connection. they are much simpler to work with and there are libraries built into both Android an iOS

Answer (score 2):

[SDL_net](http://www.libsdl.org/projects/SDL_net/) runs on iOS & Android

The functions are a bit different from Berkeley sockets, e.g. `SDLNet_CheckSockets` is more limited compared with what `select` and `poll` offers.